# Custom TCP Parameters for multiple interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp

My question is about TCP parameters in Linux. By now, I want to change the default values of:

Initial Timeout

ACK Delay

Idle Connection Timeout

I have a Linux Box with kernel 2.6.x and 2 ethernet interfaces. I know TCP is a stack that doesn't have anything to do with ethernet devices. Said that, the question: is there a way to set custom values for each interface? For example, a server listening to connections in **eth0** would use one value for **Idle Connection Timeout** and another server listening to connections in **eth1** could use a different value for that parameter.

Any considerations will be appreciated.
Best Regards,
Tiago

Answer (score 1):

Looks like delayed ACK is hard-coded [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/include/net/tcp.h#L115):

```
#define TCP_DELACK_MAX  ((unsigned)(HZ/5))      /* maximal time to delay before sending an ACK */
#if HZ >= 100
#define TCP_DELACK_MIN  ((unsigned)(HZ/25))     /* minimal time to delay before sending an ACK */
```

By idle connection timeout you probably mean TCP keep alive. 
This you also can not set per interface. [Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) it explained. 
Values that controls TCP keep alive behaviour are configured by following files:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
```

By default TCP connection had TCP keep alive disabled. Appliation willing to use the feature should enable it by calling `setsockoption(2)` with `SO_KEEPALIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't.

You can either set kernel parameters for the tcp stack (try doing a `sysctl -a | grep tcp`), or set parameters on a TCP socket (see `man tcp`), but neither will give you control over the ACK delay. This is coded in `/usr/src/<kernels>/include/net/tcp.h`, if you have the kernel source.